# Print a specific row of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
import pandas as pd
datas = [{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':(-210)}, {'A':12,'B':120}, {"A":14, "B":30}]
df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
df ["CUMSUM"] = (df["B"].cumsum())
```

I´m trying to get the following output:

1) If the column "CUMSUM" has any value lower than (-100): print just the first row in which CUMSUM < (-100), and stop running.

2) If the column "CUMSUM" has not any value lower than (-100): print just the last row, and stop running.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

datas = [{'A':10, 'B':100}, {'A':11,'B':(-210)}, {'A':12,'B':120}, {'A':14, 'B':30}]
df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
df['CUMSUM'] = (df['B'].cumsum())

if (df['CUMSUM'] < -100).any():

# 1) If the column "CUMSUM" has any value lower than (-100):
# print just the first row in which CUMSUM < (-100), and stop running.

    print(df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] < -100, :].head(1))

else:

# 2) If the column "CUMSUM" has not any value lower than (-100):
# print just the last row, and stop running.

    print(df.loc[df['CUMSUM'] >= -100, :].tail(1))
```

Comment: Ok. But I want to get only one result: just 1) or 2).  I mean, something like: iterate into the rows, if "CUMSUM" has any value lower than (-100) print this row and break, if "CUMSUM" has any value lower than (-100) print just the last row and break.

Comment: @Dan_99, I've just wrapped an if statement around my code.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much!